# How to add an element in FireStore Mappage with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore I have a document that contains a attribute mapping.
This attribute contains or can contain a lot of keys / values.

But I do not know how to add key/values ​​to this attribute

I know that, to add in the list we can use `FieldValue.arrayUnion([userUid])`.

I have try that

```
firestore.collection(questionCollection).document(object.id).updateData({attributeMapping: {key: FieldValue.increment(1)}});
```

But this deletes the other key/values already inserted.

Somebody can help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I ended up solving my problem.
I put the answer here if it ever helps someone

```
firestore.collection(questionCollection).document(object.id).setData({attributeMapping: {key: FieldValue.increment(1)}}, merge: true);
```